# How to get ST_MakeLine ready for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry, line, srid

```
CREATE VIEW new_line AS
SELECT
point1.gid,
ST_MakeLine(point1.geom, point2.geom)
FROM point1, point2
WHERE point1.gid = point2.gid;
```

It's possible to load the layer but QGIS says 'There is no entry in geometry_columns!'. The SRID is missing, too.

Comment: Read http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column

Comment: Used wrong syntax: `(ST_MakeLine(point1.geom, point2.geom)).geom::geometry(linestring, SRID) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a little bit more of the Lunar Sea answer. 
Your query is ok. The problem is that you didn't gave a name to the geometry column so qgis doesn't like it. Specify ::geometry ecc... is important but not essential if you know what is inside your table. 
It could be possible that you have to specify Multilinestring instead of Linestring.

```
CREATE VIEW new_line AS
    SELECT
    point1.gid,
    ST_MakeLine(point1.geom, point2.geom)::geometry(Linestring, SRID) as geom
    FROM point1, point2
    WHERE point1.gid = point2.gid;
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

The geom column needs registering in the view public.geometry_columns. This is done by adding '::geometry(linestring, SRID)' to the query:

```
ST_MakeLine(point1.geom, point2.geom)::geometry(linestring, SRID)
```

Thanks @user30184 for the link to [the docs](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column)

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit Lunar Sea. Short answers are likely to be deleted... even though the kernel of the answer is here we would generally like to see a bit of reference or an implementation to assist future users encountering the same problem.